# CSS show a bigger image while hover

Tags: html, css, z-index

Ive got a product page with a smaller image of the product.
Now I want to show a bigger version of this image with a colored background covering the whole page, while I hover the smaller image.

The problem is, that the bigger image flickers while I move the mouse around.
My CSS:

```
#zoomed-product-img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(162, 130, 192, 0.8);
  z-index: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#zoomed-product-img img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
}

.productsdetail-image:hover~#zoomed-product-img {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="productdetails">
    <div class="productsdetail-image">
    <img src="/assets/images/products/{{page.name}}.png" alt="Produktbild">
    </div>
    <div class="productsdetail-info">

    </div>
    <div id="zoomed-product-img">
        <img src="/assets/images/products/{{page.name}}.png" alt="Produktbild">
    </div>
```

Can you help me? Maybe my way of thinking is wrong.
I think it flickers because when I show the bigger image, it is above (z index) the small one and I am not hovering the image anymore so it disappears.

I would also love to solve this with javascript, if you can give me any advice.

Comment: Can you add the html?

Comment: Let me Try @Danny Bergs . Kindly give me 2 minutes

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify dimensions for the container of the image. This is why it is flickering. I also used `display: none;` and `display:block` to hide and show the images.

```
.productdetails {
  position: relative;
}

#zoomed-product-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

/* This is the product detail image styles */
.productsdetail-image {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.productsdetail-image:hover img {
  display: none;
}

.productsdetail-image:hover + #zoomed-product-img {
  display: block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="productdetails">
  <div class="productsdetail-image">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/animals" alt="Produktbild">
  </div>
  <div id="zoomed-product-img">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals" alt="Produktbild">
  </div>
  <div class="productsdetail-info">

  </div>
```

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/n07bt46y/

Comment: this is a nice solution, but it doesnt fit what I need. Or I am to stupid to transform it.
I need to show a bigger image in the center of my page with a colored background covering the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this in full page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.productsdetail-image img').hover(function() {
    $(this).hide();
      $('#zoomed-product-img ').show(500);
  });
  $('#zoomed-product-img .close').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
      $('.productsdetail-image img ').show();
   });
});
```

```css
.productsdetail-image img { 
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#zoomed-product-img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
#zoomed-product-img span.close {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
#zoomed-product-img img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: aUto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productdetails">
   <div class="productsdetail-image">
     <img src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals" alt="Produktbild">
  </div>
  <div id="zoomed-product-img">
    <span class="close">close</span>
    <img class="zoom-img" src="https://placeimg.com/300/300/animals" alt="Produktbild">
  </div>
  <div class="productsdetail-info">
  </div>
```

Are you wanna build something like that? Hoppefully that fiddle can help you